# CSS Conflicting Style Sheets

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

I have two style sheets which conflict with each other on several counts. Because I'm using 5, 6, and in some cases 9 or 10 complete plug-ins, each with three or fours style sheets, along with my own, conflicts arise everywhere. What is the best way to fix this problem? Is the only option to go in and modify the selectors of all of the plug-ins?

Edit: The problem is that all the plug-ins use their own style sheets which conflict with each other. The optimal, but probable impossible without modifying all the selectors, solution would to easily localize the style sheets to certain parts of the page.

Comment: I would have _hoped_ that plugin stylesheets would only target relevant elements and not clash too much with others. Having so many resources must really be killer for mobile.

Comment: It's not on the "front-end" of the website for users. It's for managers to be able to see the statistics, graphs, data collection etc from the website.

Comment: Why does it matter who it's for? Plugin authors should still be mindful of such things and use very specific selectors...

Comment: Also, because there's some confusion on this point not for just me, I guess: are you saying that your own style sheets conflict with the plugins, or that the stylesheets of the plugins conflict with each other?

Comment: @Colleen My comment was talking about the "killer for mobile" part, since this part really needed functionality more than quick load times. I think my edit should clear that all up, sorry for not be specific enough before.

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind some very basic tips for style overriding:

First, try to avoid generic class names and id's that are certain to be used by other sources.

Second, !important can override styles, but should only be used in ways that make sense...

Third, the hierarchy of the "cascade" part of css is down -> out:

So

```
#header a{
    color:#fff;
}

#header div a{
    color:#000;
}

#header div.some-class a.active{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

The bottom selector will take priority no matter where it is placed because it is targeted specifically with a horrid chain of selectors. So perhaps you need to write your css in a way that reduces the chances of being overwritten by other sources.

Comment: don't you think it's best if he sticks with selector modification and doesn't touch the css guts? I mean insofar as !important is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is definitely *not* to modify the selectors of the plugins unless you wrote the plugins yourself. You should modify your own classes/ids/css files to... not have conflicts.

Comment: The problem is that they are conflicting with each other

Comment: right - that's what I got from this question as well. Probably because he says "along with my own"

Answer (score 0):

Make your CSS as specific as possible, I would not modify the plugin unless you are confident you know your way around.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each section that you want to localise in its own div, with a specific and appropriate ID. Then mod each selector in the stylesheet to be preceded by #specificSectionID . With find/change in a decent code editor, you'll be done in five minutes. Example:

```
.headersection a {color: #DDD; background: transparent}
//becomes
#topSection .headersection a {color: #DDD; background: transparent}
```