# Why doesn't the CSS apply to div?

Tags: css, html

I want to add a footer and started by creating a div in my html like this:

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ec6608;
}
```

but for some reason, all browsers do not apply the css to the div. So the div does not have any styles. I tried positioning the div somewhere else in the html, just to be sure this is not a weird placement problem. Did the same in the css document. I also used another name for the class and I tried using an id instead. Than I tried to create the footer without a div just by using the tag footer and styled it the same way: no problem there. Why the div version won't work? How I can add my css and html files?

Comment: [It seems to work for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu3Hb/)

Comment: Please provide more code that you are using. Maybe the context is a problem

Comment: It's a specificity problem for sure

Comment: Where did you declared the css? If it is in an external stylesheet, did you actually included it? if it is within the page, are you sure you did that within a `<style>` tag?

Comment: if its on a site can you give us the url if not can you make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I tried something new, the result is very disturbing...
I added a div (over my footer div) with the class test and styled test exactly the same way. It worked fine. Than I renamed footer into test, it worked fine. But somehow, when I rename test into footer, it doesn't work again. I guess this is a new year prank ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! @Mathew I use an external stylesheet and all the other divs in my index.html are styled via that stylesheet too. They work just fine. I'm very confused...
I think I will go with another name for the class. But since I've used the name footer for my footer div class in 4 other websites I'm not sure why I have to do this....... By the way: I validated my css, it's fine. And I also checked my scripts for anything called footer. Nothing there.

Comment: i have a strong feeling that you are having css tags conflict(href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868454/css-conflicting-style-sheets) ...which might be getting overlooked by you!!

Comment: I uploaded the website on my server for you. It is not ready yet, but that should make it easier to understand. The class is now called "prank" (the last div in the index.html)...
http://www.informationlovers.com/projekte/occa/

Comment: Looks the styles are applied in IE11 from your link

Comment: Styles are applied in chrome too,
I guess it might be a cache problem. try clearing cache in your browser.

Comment: It works now, since I used the new name for the class. But I still don't know what the problem was. I allready tried solving it by cleaning the cache, but thank you @shem86

Comment: Well it also works if I edit the class name to "footer" on both html and css in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't link the css file in the html page.
This might help.
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link_to_your_css_file" />`
Do this in the head section of the html code.

Answer (score 0):

If you've pre-defined `CSS` rule for `.footer` then try to **overwrite** it like this:

```
.footer {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 80px !important;
    background-color: #ec6608 !important;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using !important as much as possible…